# Dynamically Create View with Many Shapes

Tags: android, dynamic, view, android-drawable

I am trying to **dynamically** create views made up of different shapes. Each view will be slightly different like these:

View 1

[image: View 1]

View 2

[image: View 2].

Once I have the information, how can I construct a view which contains multiple shapes like the ones above?

I tried using `drawable` but I cannot, because I want to do this dynamically and the lengths of the objects are fixed. What should I use to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could create a [custom view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) for that. With it you can paint whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for replying. On using custom view, I have to use paint with canvas to do the drawings. But that complicates my app because I am using gridlayout to display all my views together. Hence I cannot draw statically.